# Booting into recovery mode shows blue Recovery Booting text, then gets stuck with a black screen

Tags: recovery-mode

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S4
Android: 4.2.2 / XXUBMGA

I am on [djembey's pre-rooted slim XXUBMGA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2250824).

Recovery Mode does not work for me. From OFF mode, I press <kbd>Vol Up</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd>. Then, I see a small blue "Recovery Booting..." text in the top left corner of the screen, but nothing happens. It stays black. If I stop pressing the three buttons, the phone boots normally.

Download mode works for me (VolUp+Home+Power), and I am able to flash using Odin.

How do I fix the recovery mode? Do I need to flash stock recovery again? Would I lose my data if I do so?

Similar question:
[Blank screen when trying to boot into recovery mode on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47986/blank-screen-when-trying-to-boot-into-recovery-mode-on-samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When small blue writing appears, let go of just the power button. It should then boot into recovery. [Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=43929363&postcount=3729).

Disclaimer: I am DLAddict on XDA.

Answer (score 0):

i already try download many stock firmware and flash with many version odin but still stuck on samsung logo with blue recovery booting..

My problem solved with kies.i used Tool-Firmware Upgrade and Initialisation..u need to enter your smsung model then enter your S/N.(need stable internet connection).just wait until complete 100%,it ask u to restart..all my software and my data in my internal storage still there..Samsung Galaxy Mega 6.3 GT-I9205.